# Vue - Performance issues on table filters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to manipulate a Vue table.
I've multiple filters to filter table's rows.

My filters are actually working, but I've performance issues.

**The problem is : when the filter removes rows, everything is fine. But when it adds rows, performance is really dropping down...**

I mean, I only have 50 rows, and it takes 2 seconds to display them, from 0 rows to 50 rows...

I think that I missed something...

**This is my code**

I've one input to filter on name field (this is simplified, I actually have 4 filters), and I filter on the method etdLineDisplayed which is calculated the filter.

This is my template :

```
<input type="text" v-model="filterRow" class="form-control"/>   
<b-table
    :items="etdLineDisplayed"
    :fields="fields"
>
[...]
</b-table>
```

And this is where my items are :

```
computed: {
    etdLineDisplayed() {
        let itemsFiltered = this.filterRow !== '' ? this.etdLinesData.filter(_ => _.name.includes(this.filterRow.toLowerCase()) : this.allItems;
        return itemsFiltered;
    }
},
```

Comment: Have you tried using the b-table's filter functionality instead of yours? https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#filtering

Comment: Yes I did, and it's also slow...

Comment: Can you post a fiddle, codepen, or example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from where you performance issues come from but I know that memoization can be a really good thing to do for tables, check this article: https://www.maxpou.fr/vuejs-performance-improvement-with-memoization

It will essentially not recompute all the non-moving heavy parts, just bring it up back. Thing that cannot be done with `computed` because you cannot give any params to it, hence relying on `methods`..

Answer (score 0):

https://mmichaelid.medium.com/bootstrap-vue-b-table-rest-api-integration-with-filters-pagination-sorting-and-browser-history-bd6eb8ccdc5f 
This article shows some filtering pagination and sorting server-side with Java and on the frontend with Vue and b-table. You can use it as a guide for the template in front.